# How should I modify my css to make the image getting closer to my text when I narrow the browser?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, responsive

guys I am new to front end development and I am trying to learn from building a page.

Here is the demo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-boyd-xscgd

it looks fine on full-screen but when I narrow the viewport. The picture seems to be getting far away from the text and the gap between them are getting bigger as the picture shows.
[image]

The effect I wanted to achieve is that when I narrow the browser the picture would get closer to the text(and there would be overlap between them). When it is viewed on phone, the picture will become the background picture of the screen. like this

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Just a suggestion_ but it might help to get the right advice _ Add the `React` tag to your queston

Comment: @inputforcolor thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image element to

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

in the CSS file. That should work.

Comment: Shouldn't they also adjust the z-index?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That would help to put it behind the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can do this with CSS media query. Here is a sample, I hope you can tweak around and make it work for you.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="txt">
      <h1>Your Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pic">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    #main{
       width:100%;
    }
    #txt{
       width:50%;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    #pic{
       width:48%;
       display: inline-block;
    }

   @media (max-width: 500px) {
     #pic{
       display: none;
     }
     #main{
       background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500");
       background-size: cover;
     }
     #txt{
       width:100%;
       text-align: center;
     }
   }
```

Reduce your browser's size to smaller than 500px and refresh, you will see the change. If you want to do this in more dynamic way, you have to use javascript/jquery.